# Spacy tokenizer to handle final period in sentence

Tags: tokenize, spacy

I'm using Spacy to tokenize sentences, and I know that the text I pass to the tokenizer will always be a single sentence.

In my tokenization rules, I would like non-final periods (".") to be attached to the text before it so I updated the suffix rules to remove the rules that split on periods (this gets abbreviations correctly).

The exception, however, is that the very last period should be split into a separate token.

I see that the latest version of Spacy allows you to split tokens after the fact, but I'd prefer to do this within the Tokenizer itself so that other pipeline components are processing the correct tokenization.

Comment: Try adding a `r'^\.$'` rule to the suffixes.

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Comment: The suffix regexes match the text after splitting on white space so that regex doesn't work.  There is a lot of code to the tokenizer so let me think about how to do this concisely...

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution that uses some post processing after the tokenizer:

- I added "." to suffixes so that a period is always split into its own token.
- I then used a regex to find non-final periods, generated a span with `doc.char_span`, and merged the span to a single token with `span.merge`.

Would be nice to be able to do this within the tokenizer if anyone knows how to do that.